# Magento 2 - Get order custom attribute data using rest api

Tags: magento2, orders, api, rest-api

While i am trying to get order custom attribute data using rest api it's coming as string. But magento returning all other data as **JSON**. Does anyone have any idea how to make this look like json?

***Actual result:***

```
extra_fee": [
        "{\"code\":\"mp_extra_fee_rule_2_auto\",\"title\":\"Credit Card Surcharge\",\"label\":\"Credit Card Surcharge\",\"value\":17.22,\"value_excl_tax\":17.22,\"value_incl_tax\":17.22,\"base_value\":17.22,\"base_value_incl_tax\":17.22,\"rf\":\"0\",\"display_area\":\"3\",\"apply_type\":\"1\",\"rule_label\":\"Credit Card Surcharge\"}",
        "{\"code\":\"mp_extra_fee_rule_3_option_0\",\"title\":\"110\",\"label\":\"110\",\"value\":1148,\"base_value\":1148,\"value_incl_tax\":1148,\"value_excl_tax\":1148,\"base_value_incl_tax\":1148,\"rf\":\"0\",\"display_area\":\"3\",\"apply_type\":\"2\",\"rule_label\":\"Manage Titles Discount\"}"
    ]
```

***Expected Result:***

```
extra_fee": [
    {
    "code":"mp_extra_fee_rule_2_auto",
    "title":"Credit Card Surcharge",
    "label":"Credit Card Surcharge",
    "value":17.22,
    "value_excl_tax":17.22,
    "value_incl_tax":17.22,
    "base_value":17.22,
    "base_value_incl_tax":17.22,
    "rf":"0",
    "display_area":"3",
    "apply_type":"1",
    "rule_label":"Credit Card Surcharge"
    },
    {
    "code":"mp_extra_fee_rule_3_option_0",
    "title":"110",
    "label":"110",
    "value":1148,
    "base_value":1148,
    "value_incl_tax":1148,
    "value_excl_tax":1148,
    "base_value_incl_tax":1148,
    "rf":"0",
    "display_area":"3",
    "apply_type":"2",
    "rule_label":"Manage Titles Discount"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields often have values containing encoded JSON because the Magento code itself doesn't try to understand how the custom fields function.

In your example above, if you iterate the values in the extra_fee array and parse them as JSON, you'll get usable objects.